# OpenVPN performance

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, performance

I setup an OpenVPN tunnel between two hosts with 50Mbit/s connection. 
If I test the speed of the endpoints, it's give the 50Mbit speed exactly. 
But when I do the same over OpenVPN connection, it's limited to 20MBit/s.

Meanwhile the VPN servers (both are rackable servers with high performance) has no significant performance issue. Under 10% CPU usage always.

What would be that setting on OpenVPN what can cause that ?

Answer (score 5):

How are you measuring throughput?

OpenVPN only adds 69 bytes of overhead, which is less than 5% on a 1431 byte packet.

One troubleshooting step may be to see if your clients/servers are trying to send 1500 byte packets that get fragmented, which will severely degrade performance.

Comment: right on point.  if you're sending 1500-byte packets, each one is being split and sent as two packets, dropping performance precipitously.

Comment: A test the network speed with speedtest.net site, and with iperf. I will chech the package fragmentation, maybe this cause the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Be sure you're using "proto udp" as tcp in tcp is [known to be problematic](http://sites.inka.de/bigred/devel/tcp-tcp.html).

Compare the throughput numbers for UDP versus TCP transport [here](http://www1.cse.wustl.edu/~jain/cse567-08/ftp/ovpn/index.html#sec3.3).

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you should expect the same speed in a VPN tunnel. Since the packets have to be encrypted and decrypted it does cause some overhead.

I'm not sure if that could explain a 30Mbps drop but that can explain why you don't have 50Mbps.